# HELP Please - CSS Width Problems on IE8

Tags: css, width

I'm very new to website development, and don't know much about HTML or CSS. I do know however that the template that I've chosen to use from my hosting site is problematic on IE8, but I don't know how to fix it.  The main content box where the page's text goes is slightly more to the left than centered. I don't know how to get it to match the other borders on the page.

Can someone please tell me how I can fix the width and overall page dimensions on my website?

Website: PineBarrensAnimals.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="{%MetaCharset%}" />
   <meta name="description" content="{%MetaDescription%}" />
   <meta name="keywords" content="{%MetaKeywords%}" />
   <title>{%MetaTitle%}</title>
    <style>
   html, body {
height: 100%;
padding-top:10px;
margin:10px;
}
body {
background: #3F3F3F url("images/tile.jpg");
background-position: top center;
font-family: "Arial";
font-size: 11px;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
a, a:link {
text-decoration: underline;
color:#FFF;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color:#FFF;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: underline;
color:#FFF;
}

#container {
width: 774px;
height: auto !important;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}

#core_header {
width: 762px;;
height: 302px;
background: url(images/header.gif);
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
position:relative;
left:7px;
}

#header_text
{
position:relative;
right:420px;
top:40px;
font-size:16pt;
float:right;
font-weight:bold;
}

#header_text span {
   font-size: 12pt;
   }

img
{
margin:5px;
}

#core_left {
margin: 0;
width: 774px;
height:auto;
}
#core_right {
margin: 0;
float: left;
width:750px;
min-height:100%;
height:auto !important;
height:100%;
background: #4D7942;
color:#000;
margin-left:10px;
border-left: 4px solid #FFF;
border-right: 4px solid #FFF;
}

.content-box
{

padding:6px;
height:auto !important;
float:left;
width: 720px;
margin-bottom:10px;
font-family: "Arial";
font-size: 11px;
color:#FFF;
margin-left:10px;
}
.tumb
{
float: left;
margin-right:5px;
padding:0px;
}

.pagination
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
}

#footer {
width:758px;
background:  url(images/footer.gif) bottom center no-repeat;
text-align: center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:0px;
height:26px;
clear:both;
position:relative;
left:2px;
}

#footer2
{
clear:both;
height:10px;
background: url(images/footer.jpg);
width:758px;
margin-left:10px;
}


h2
{
font-family: "Verdana", Lucida Handwriting, sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
height:25px;
}
h3
{
font-family: "Verdana", Lucida Handwriting, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
height:22px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
color:#FFF;
width:718px;
background: url(images/content_header.jpg) bottom left repeat-x;
margin-bottom:5px;
font-weight:bold;
}
h4
{
font-family: "Verdana", Lucida Handwriting, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
}


#navcontainer li {
color:#FFF;
display:inline;
position:relative;
height:25px;
width:100px;
padding-left: 55px;
padding-top:20px;
top:19px;
}

#navcontainer ul {
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
width: 774px;
list-style-type: none;
background: url("images/menu_bg.gif");
height:60px;
}
#navcontainer a, #navcontainer a:visited {
display:inline;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:13px;

}
#navcontainer a:hover {
margin:0px;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom:2px solid #FFF;


}
div#sth {
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 10px;
   }

div#sth span {
   margin: 0 auto;
   }
   </style>

      <!--[if IE]>
     <style type="text/css">

     #footer
     {
      left:1px; 
     }

     #core_right
     {
      height:300px;
      margin-left:5px;
     }
     .content-box
     {
      margin-left:5px;
     }

     </style>
     <![endif]-->

   </head>




<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="core_header">
<div id="header_text">{%WebsiteName%}<br /><span>{%WebsiteSlogan%}</span></div>
</div>
<div id="core_container">
<div id="core_container2">
<div id="core_left">
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
{%menu_start=1%}
<li><a href="{%menu_href%}">{%menu_display%}</a></li>
{%menu_end=1%} 
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="core_right"><!-- Your content goes here -->
<div class="content-box">
<h3>{%name%}</h3>
{%content%}</div>
<!-- End of content --></div>
</div>
<div id="footer2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="sth"><span>{%WebsiteFooter%}</span></div>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you, 
 - Danny B

Answer (score 2):

This should be a case of standard web debugging:

First, you need a DOM inspector (and know how to use it).

Then you need to remove various formatting from your site until you are down to the minimum that still shows the problem.

Hopefully a minimal version should make the problem apparent.
If not, post a minimal version of your HTML code here, and we'll take a look.

But few people here want to dig through all the irrelevant parts of your code.

**EDIT** Through trial and error, I fixed it this way:

> In the first #core_right, changed WIDTH to 758.
>
> In the second #core_right (within [if IE]), changed MARGIN-LEFT to 10.

I think that does it.

Comment: DOM inspector and a must have in general: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
<!--[if IE]>
```

To

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
```

The problem is with the margins added to the the right panel and footer in that conditional block. IE 8 doesn't need them, but I'm guessing IE 7 does.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm going to try some of these out, and see if it fixes the problem.  

To be honest w/ you, I've never even heard of a DOM Inspector before, but if the tips on this page don't correct the problem, I'll definitely give it a shot.  

 Thanks, 
   - Danny B.

Answer (score 1):

In this block

```
 <!--[if IE]>
     <style type="text/css">

     #footer
     {
      left:1px; 
     }

     #core_right
     {
      height:300px;
      margin-left:5px;
     }
     .content-box
     {
      margin-left:5px;
     }

     </style>
     <![endif]-->
```

remove the `margin-left: 5px` in `core_right` and the `left: 1px` and you *should* be there, although I can't say whether it'll be in all browsers or just IE8 (Use [**IETester**](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to check with the others.)

Answer (score 1):

I want to say thank you to everyone.

I used the following 2 tips:

1)  In the first #core_right, changed WIDTH to 758.

```
In the second #core_right (within [if IE]), changed MARGIN-LEFT to 10.
```

2)  
        To

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
```

I tried the website on IE 8, Safari, and Firefox and it looks fine now.

- Danny B.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please up-vote the answers that helped, and select one as the "Accepted" answer.

Answer (score 0):

If "div#core_right" had a 10px left-margin, instead of a 5px, it would look fine in IE8.